# How to use useState to only update specific object from array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I just implemented a like-system functionality into my React application but now I've been struggling to change the state of the specific object instead of the whole array of objects..which is the current behaviour.

```
{post.likes.some(u => u.user == _id) ? (
  <Button
    variant="link"
    size={`sm`}
    className={`mr-1`}
    onClick={() => {removeLike(post._id) ; setIconColor('success') ; setLikes(post.likes.length) }}
  >
    <i className={`fa fa-heart text-${iconColor} like mr-1`}></i>{likes}
  </Button>
) : (
  <Button
    variant="link"
    size={`sm`}
    className={`mr-1`}
    onClick={() => {addLike(post._id) ; setIconColor('danger') ; setLikes(post.likes.length) }}
  >
    <i className={`fa fa-heart text-${iconColor} like mr-1`}></i>{likes}
  </Button>
)}
```

As mentioned before, this is inside a component which runs throuhg the array of objects.

Right now, this is what I have in my component just before the return statement:

```
const [iconColor, setIconColor] = useState('');
const [likes, setLikes] = useState(0);
```

If I run it as-is, it updates the state on every single object instead of the object in which I clicked on. This is my actual problem:
[useState() updating muliple objects](https://ibb.co/vYJjgTF)

UPDATE: I'm using redux-thunk also:

```
// @desc     Like a post
// @route    PUT /api/v1/posts/:id/like
// @access   Private
// @status   DONE
export const addLike = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.put(`/api/v1/posts/${id}/like`);

    return dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_LIKES,
      payload: {
        id,
        likes: res.data
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response && err.response.statusText, status: err.response && err.response.status }
    });
  }
};

// @desc     Dislike a post
// @route    PUT /api/v1/posts/:id/dislike
// @access   Private
// @status   DONE
export const removeLike = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.put(`/api/v1/posts/${id}/dislike`);

    return dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_LIKES,
      payload: {
        id,
        likes: res.data
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return dispatch({
      type: POST_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response && err.response.statusText, status: err.response && err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

Those function then return a dispatch that connects to my reducer:

```
case UPDATE_LIKES:
  return {
      ...state,
      likes: state.timeline.map((post) =>
        post._id === payload.id && { [post._id]: payload.likes.length }
      ),
      // like: !state.like,
      // likes: console.log(
      //   state.timeline.map(post =>
      //     post._id === payload.id ? { ...post, likes: payload.likes } : post
      //   )
      // ),
      loading: false
  };
```

Comment: Where is the code you are using to update a specific object? Please include *that* functionality. It would be better to include your entire component code as we can see how you've setup state, where you try to update it, etc.. a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.

Comment: You can now check my updated question. I added more details about it.

Comment: In `UPDATE_LIKES`, when you map `state.timeline` I think you don't return all the elements that don't match on id, or instead, they return/map `false`. What does your `likes` array represent?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to have an array of variable `likes`. Currently you’re just changing the value of same variable many times. Simply have the like array's index same as your parent array's index. Or even better: store the like count inside the object of the post/card.

Answer (score 0):

To only update specific object from array of objects, you can try something like:

```
let stateObj = {
    one: [],
    two: [],
    three: [],
    // and so on
}
```

So you can get an specific object or array from this big state like:

```
stateObj.one
```

and now you can do what ever you want to do with this and once its values are updated just replace it in the original one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track `likes` for each post. For that you can use some mapping like `{ post_id: like_count}`

So your state will become:

```
const [likes, setLikes] = useState({});
```

And click listener will be:

```
onClick={() => {addLike(post._id) ; setIconColor('danger') ; setLikes({...likes, [post._id]: post.likes.length}) }}
```

Displaying like count will be:

```
<i className={`fa fa-heart text-${iconColor} like mr-1`}></i>{likes[post._id] || 0}
```

Comment: I did as you mentioned (without using redux-thunk) but it did not work, it kept acting the same, right now I'm trying to transfer it into redux-thunk so I can try to make it more easy to get help since I've seen most people have knowledge about it.

Comment: The like count should be now independent. But The color might change for all as `setIconColor('danger')` might be changing a global color. You would have to do similar logic for tracking icon color.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, you need states for this. As far as I understand from your code, you can achieve the same as below.

```js
{post.likes.some(u => u.user == _id) ? (
  <Button
    variant="link"
    size={`sm`}
    className={`mr-1`}
    onClick={() => {removeLike(post._id)}}
  >
    <i className={`fa fa-heart text-danger like mr-1`}></i>{post.likes.length}
  </Button>
) : (
  <Button
    variant="link"
    size={`sm`}
    className={`mr-1`}
    onClick={() => {addLike(post._id)}}
  >
    <i className={`fa fa-heart text-success like mr-1`}></i>{post.likes.length}
  </Button>
)}
```

and your `addLike` and `removeLike` functions should update `post` which will force re-render your component. And hence it should work as expected.